# Getting null while trying to get an object propriety inside localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this code:

```
let cart = [];
let item1 = {
        name: "CD - Animal",
        price: "12",
        qntd: "0"
    };

let item2 = {
    name: "CD - Cannibal",
    price: "10",
    qntd: "0"
};

$("button").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var li = $(this).parent();
    var quantity = $(li).find('input[type=number]').val();
    eval($(this).val()).qntd = quantity;
    cart.push(eval($(this).val()));
    console.log(item1.qntd);
    localStorage.setItem(cart, JSON.stringify(cart));
    console.log(cart[0].name);
    console.log(JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem(cart[0].name))));
});
```

But `cart[0].name` does not return the object's name, instead, returns null.

`cart[0]` returns the object correctly, `0:{name: "CD - Animal", price: "12", qntd: "3"}`, but when I try to get `cart[0].name`, it returns null instead of "CD - Animal".

HTML:

```
<div class="card-content animal">
    <form style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <input type = "number" class = "qntd" placeholder="Quantidade" style = "width: 100%; margin-top: -20px;" maxlength="10">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" value = "item1">Add
            <i class="material-icons right">attach_money</i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `eval($(this).val()).qntd = quantity;` DO NOT USE EVAL! :)

Comment: I need your HTML file

Comment: you set the item with a "key" of whatever cart (toString) is ... then you try to read using `cart[0]` ... which wont be the same as `cart` ... not surprising it doesn't work - it's like setting the value with key name "hello" and expecting "goodbye" to read that value back

Comment: I needed eval to the transform the value of the button, which it's an string (item1), to an previously created object (item1), so I can add it's qntd. Couldn't find another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use index on the parsed `localStorage` item.

Try `JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem(cart)))[0].name` instead of

`JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem(cart[0].name)));`

Comment: This will be equivalent to `...getItem('[object Object]')` if `cart` is an Array containing an object.

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is eval is bad and you are using it and the variables you are referencing are not in global scope and that is where eval is looking. Use a better data structure and do not rely on variables.

```
var items = [
        {
            name: "CD - Animal",
            price: "12",
            qntd: "0"
        }, {
        name: "CD - Cannibal",
        price: "10",
        qntd: "0"
    }
]
```

Now you can just reference it with `items[0].qntd`

or it you want to use a key, switch it to an object instead of an array.

```
var items = {
     item1: {
       name: "CD - Animal",
       price: "12",
       qntd: "0"
     }, 
     item2: {
        name: "CD - Cannibal",
        price: "10",
        qntd: "0"
    }
 }
```